# Some Old Arxiv.org papers PdfLatex Problem

Tags: pdftex, arxiv

Some 90's papers in arvix.org do not produce proper PDF. When the PDF is generated, some texts are cut off from the bottom of every single page. Here is a link to a paper in the arxiv which demonstrates the problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9405011

There are a lot of important old papers in the arxiv which have this issues. I tried downloading the Latex source file first and then compile it, but it doesn't run, shows a lot of errors.

Is there a direct way to solve this problem? There is of course always a brute force method: First download the paper latex source file from the arxiv, then change the document class to something like `amsart' and then change all of the other codes in the file to the to appropriate amsart document class codes.

This process becomes practically impossible for a long paper.

It would be a big help if there were some direct ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @Campa, I am using a macintosh machine with MacTex 2016 distribution, which supposedly comes with built in amstex. Is there any special way to compile in amstex?

Comment: the text is all there so as an alternative to rerunning the tex you could use pdf2ps, fix up the bounding box to be less tight and then ps2pdf. It should probably be reported to the archive

Comment: I didn't download the source, but most amstex documents can be processed with plain tex (as they input amstex.tex explicitly)

Comment: @campa, @David: Thanks for your help! Although none of the suggestions worked for me. I found another post in stackexchange where they discussed the exact same problem as mine. And it solved my problem. It was just a matter of adding an `\input amstex' before the document class and run it with PlainTex in Texshop. Here is the link to that discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225856/rescuing-compiling-old-tex-file-starting-with-input-amstex

Comment: @user80473 -- since you found the answer with another question -- and were specific about which one! -- i've voted to close this as a duplicate.